# How to split access for two resources inside the same google cloud's project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-iam, google-cloud-iam

I have two users: `user1@gmail.com` and `user1@gmail.com`, and I have a google cloud project `X`. Inside `X`, I have two VMs: `vm1` and `vm2`. How can I grant access to `start` and `stop` action on `vm1` and `vm2` for users: `user1@gmail.com` and `user1@gmail.com`, but access to `vm1` should have `user1@gmail.com`, and access to `vm2` should have `user1@gmail.com`? If it is possible please show a scenario to do it.

Answer (score 2):

The parent resource to Compute Engine is the project resource. Typically you grant IAM roles at the project level for an identity.

Compute Engine supports resource-level access control. This means that you can grant access to one Compute Engine VM resource and not all Compute Engine VMs in a project. A typical Compute Engine VM consists of multiple resources such as the instance, disks, snapshots, images, etc. Each item is a resource that requires permissions.

To grant a user the ability to "effectively" use a Compute Engine instance assign the role `roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1`. This role allows a user to manage the instance, but not create new instances.

```
gcloud compute instances add-iam-policy-binding <RESOURCE-NAME> \
--member=user:<EMAIL-ADDRESS> \
--role=roles/compute.instanceAdmin.v1"
```

[Compute Instance Admin (v1) role](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/iam#compute.instanceAdmin.v1)

[gcloud compute instances add-iam-policy-binding](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/add-iam-policy-binding)